# Does the order of extern and static matter?

Tags: c#, static-methods, .net-1.0

Comparing two files (old and new), I see:

```
private extern static void SipShowIM(uint dwFlag);
```

...in the old file, and:

```
private static extern void SipShowIM(uint dwFlag);
```

...in the new file.

Why they got changed I don't know; does it matter which comes first, the extern or the static?

### UPDATE

Resharper must have done this, because I know I didn't do this (directly) but here's another difference between old:

```
public volatile static bool ProcessCommands = true;
```

...and new:

```
public static volatile bool ProcessCommands = true;
```

Comment: Have you noticed a difference in behavior?

Comment: No, but what difference would I notice? I didn't notice any difference when the earthQuake occurred in Iran/Pakistan yesterday, but that doesn't mean it didn't effect anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the order of those keywords does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

*Well*, I don't believe there is a difference between this two usage. I just consider the code of *[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* page, I tried the both way (`extern static` and `static extern`) and the both code generate the same [IL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_language) code.

```
.method public hidebysig static int32  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       41 (0x29)
  .maxstack  4
  .locals init ([0] string myString,
           [1] int32 CS$1$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "Enter your message: "
  IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::Write(string)
  IL_000b:  nop
  IL_000c:  call       string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
  IL_0011:  stloc.0
  IL_0012:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0013:  call       native int [mscorlib]System.IntPtr::op_Explicit(int32)
  IL_0018:  ldloc.0
  IL_0019:  ldstr      "My Message Box"
  IL_001e:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_001f:  call       int32 ProgramConsole.Program::MessageBox(native int,
                                                                string,
                                                                string,
                                                                int32)
  IL_0024:  stloc.1
  IL_0025:  br.s       IL_0027
  IL_0027:  ldloc.1
  IL_0028:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

So, my money is for **NO**.

Answer (score 2):

No, according to the C# specification, all method modifier orderings are equivalent. Version 4.0, section B.2.7, page 493:

> method-modifiers:
>       method-modifier
>       method-modifiers method-modifier
>
> method-modifier:
>       new
>       public
>       protected
>       internal
>       private
>       static
>       virtual
>       sealed
>       override
>       abstract
>       extern

This clearly isn't a static constructor, but on page 497 (still section B.2.7), both orders are explicitly called out:

> static-constructor-modifiers:
>       extern<sub>opt</sub> static
>       static extern<sub>opt</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The order of method modifiers doesn't matter. It is however usually written as `static extern`.

Tools like StyleCop complain about that: `SA1206: The 'static' keyword must come before the 'other' keyword in the element declaration.`
It is just a matter of coding style.